# Created a new subdomain with same content. Should I add a redirect in my old subdomain?

Tags: wp-admin, redirect

I'm managing our WordPress site and we had a name change in the subdomain. Instead of changing the subdomain name, our IT created a new subdomain name and we just copied everything from the old one.

We have existing users in the old subdomain. Do we simply create a redirect? After creating a redirect, can I still access the WordPress Admin Dashboard?

Note: I only have access to WP Admin Dashboard and not the FTP.